# How to use Grid and Segment in @fluentui/react-northstar without borders or Horizontal lines?

Tags: reactjs, tsx, fluent-ui

This is my code

```
import { Grid, Segment } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";

Usage:

<Grid columns="repeat(4, 1fr)" rows="50px 150px">
  <Segment
    color="brand"
    content="Header"
    inverted
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 4',
    }}
  />
  <Segment
    color="green"
    content="Menu"
    inverted
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 1',
    }}
  />
  <Segment
    content="Content"
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 3',
    }}
  />
</Grid>
```

The horizontal lines appear around each segments and around the Grid.
The inline style using  border:'none'  or anything relater is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the default box-shadow CSS value currently set to
`box-shadow: rgb(34 36 38 / 15%) 0px 1px 1px 1px;`

Add this to your style class
`boxShadow: 'none'`